How to verify only using the given CA file, not against all trusted CAs on the system?
I have a Python package that uses Requests. I create a Session object with verify=[A CA File]. It appears that Requests will use this, plus any system-defined certificates, to verify the connection. Is there any way to disable this behavior?
One of my clients does not have the same trust store as I do, and on their system the connection fails. I already know that this is because the certificate I am explicitly using isn't correct, but since that fact was masked in my program due to the correct cert being in my trust store, I didn't know. I'd like to be able to test properly next time.
Edit:
Here's a simple proof:
Generate a random self-signed cert, or else just grab one from a random site on the internet. Then use it in the second command below.
import requests

r = requests.get("https://google.com", verify=True, timeout=10)
r.raise_for_status()


r = requests.get("https://google.com", verify="cert.pem", timeout=10)
r.raise_for_status()

print("Everything worked!")

No matter what you pass in, Google will be in your PC's trust store, and it'll work.

How do you know that Requests falls back to system-defined certificates? I can't find any evidence of this in the docs or the source code (though I didn't dig into the source in great detail).

@Thomas I updated my original post with an example.

I took a peek at the source for requests and found this comment:
https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/23540c93cac97c763fe59e843a08fa2825aa80fd/src/requests/certs.py#L10C1-L12C20

If you are packaging Requests, e.g., for a Linux distribution or a managed
environment, you can change the definition of where() to return a separately
packaged CA bundle
This is supported by the docs as well:
https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/advanced/#ca-certificates
which states that requests merely relies on the certifi package.
so, you can look at the certifi source and figure out how to monkey patch the where function.
https://github.com/certifi/python-certifi/blob/master/certifi/core.py
I don't see anything in the certifi source that reads from a place other than the pem file packaged with it.
Perhaps you and your client have different versions of python/certfi installed on your systems and aligning them would help?
Thanks,
Mark

Unfortunately this doesn't work.  with patch("requests.certs.where", return_value=""); requests.get("https://google.com", verify="cert.pem") This still works perfectly fine with a bogus cert. where isn't even called once.
